# Using jQuery to walk DOM, return HTML attributes from node

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-traversal

I want to walk through the DOM and identify the HTML attributes of certain nodes. For example the class value for all  tags.

The following code was suggest by another member of Stackoverflow for walking the DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/FJeaY/

It works well and I can use it to identify the ID of a node and it's parents. It's also pretty easy to filter for hyperlinks:

```
walk_the_DOM(document.body, function(node) {
    if(node.nodeName == "A")
        alert(node.nodeName + ' id: ' + node.id);
});
```

However I am unsure what to use to identify the class (or any other HTML attribute). Everything I've tried so far from searching the jQuery documentation has failed.

Any ideas appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try `node.className` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function in question actually does not use jQuery at all and the jQuery documentation is not suited for learning about the DOM in general.

Have a look at the [MDC `HTMLElement` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element). What you want is the [`className` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className):

```
walk_the_DOM(document.body, function(node) {
    if(node.nodeName == "A") {
        alert(node.nodeName + ' class: ' + node.className);
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the link to the reference Felix. You're totally right, the base code I had wasn't jQuery. What I'm planning to do with each node will involve jQuery and I managed to get myself confused.

Comment: @Tama: Well, if you plan to use jQuery anyway, then you could just do: `$('a').each(function(){/* do you stuff here */)`. This will probably be faster as jQuery makes use of browser methods if available.

Answer (score 1):

[`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) can be used for testing if a specific class is among the classes assigned to the element. Will return either true or false.

```
$(node).hasClass('myclass')
```

Or you can use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the `class` attribute of an element.

```
var klassz=$(node).attr('class');
```

Instead of the latter, you can simply use `node.className` either.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/tahir/7gfuT/

This code is using DOM directly (just to clarify the concepts). You can use jquery wrapper functions as suggested by bazmegakapa to simplify the access to DOM attributes

Comment: Thank you Tahir, also very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. The clicking on the little triangle besides the answer pointing upwards is another way to say thanks on StackOverflow ;)